# Why my Xcode4.5 doesn't has iPhone(Retina 4-inch) and iPhone(Retina 3.5inch)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Today, I update the Xcode4.5 and install it on my computer which has a earlier version Xcode4.3, after installing I open Xcode4.5, when I want to run my app, there is only IOS Device, iPad 6.0 Simulator and iPhone 6.0 Simulator. How can I test my app on both iPhone 4-inch and iPhone 3.5-inch, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the setting in the iPhone simulator.
[image: Simulator device changing]

If you app will not will up the entire screen, you are probably missing the `Default-568h@2x.png` which needs to be `640 x 1136` pixels.